# Looping delayed task

Tags: android, handler, delay, runnable

I have a code which loops a given method a number of times, but the for loop is executed in one wait itself. That is, for the given code :

```
for(int j=3;j>=1; j--)
{
final int k=j;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        randomMethod(k);
        Toast.makeText(someService.this, "works!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}, 10000);
}
```

The code executes completely within 10 seconds instead of the required 30 seconds. After executing run() shouldn't the for loop wait for the delay to finish?

How do I correct this?

Comment: change 2nd param in postDelayed method from 10000 to 30000

Comment: No, the thing is even if I change it to 30000 it should work for 90000ms, but it works only for the first delay which is 30000.

Comment: if you 10000 to 30000 then why should it work for 90000ms ? currently you are just posting new Handler in every  30000 instead of increasing time for delay

Comment: How about trying ``postDelayed(..., j * 10000)`` ? And no, for loop does not wait for ``postDelayed`` method to return in 10000ms but ``postDelayed`` works asynchronously.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I'm looping the handler, right? So when j is 3 it should wait for 10 seconds, execute my method. Then, j becomes 2 waits for another 10 seconds and so on. I want to get that. If this is the wrong code for it, what is the right way?

Comment: @harism So how do I get the delay to execute a function repeatedly?

Comment: create Timer, which every 10 seconds will call postDelayed

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji A count down timer? Didn't work, my code kept crashing.

Comment: crashing? why? maybe u made something wrong?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : That wouldn't work, the variable would have to be final to be accessed inside run.

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji Must've been another part of the code crashing my count down timer. Worked this time.

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji Answer the question, please. I need to accept the answer. You brought it up first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int REFRESH_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;
int counter = 3;
...

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(), 0, REFRESH_INTERVAL);
...
private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    public void run() {
       randomMethod(counter--);
       Toast.makeText(someService.this, "works!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I think, there is no need in `Handler` and `postDelayed()`, because `Timer` doing this work

Comment: I also think that Timer is the best option for that. Thanks for that clue.